# how do I access this item?

Tags: perl, data-dumper

I am using Data::Dumper. My code is:

```
use Data::Dumper;
blah, blah, blah.....
print Dumper \@data;
```

My output is:

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        'Dave',
        'Green',
        '5',
      ],
      [
        'Bob',
        'Yellow',
        '4',
      ]
    ];
```

How do I access 'Bob' or '5'? Also, how can I turn @data into a hash or variable in order to put the entire contents into a database?

EDIT: @data is created from reading the contents of a file:

```
while (<PARSE>) {
    push @data, [unpack $template, $_]
}
```

Comment: How did you make `@data` in the first place?  What ways of accessing the data have you tried?  Have you read any documentation on Perl's data structures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = ( [ 'Dave', 'Green', '5', ], [ 'Bob', 'Yellow', '4', ] );
print $data[0]->[2], "\n";  # 5
print $data[1]->[0], "\n";  # Bob
```

`@data` is an array of arrays. A hash consists of a key and a corresponding value. In order to convert the array into a hash, you have to assign one of the elements to be the key and the rest the value.

### Note

Alternative syntax:

`$data[0]->[1]` is equivalent to `$data[0][1]`.

### Refer

- [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) - Perl Data Structures Cookbook
- [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) - Mark's very short tutorial about references

**Acknowledgements:**

*Bill Ruppert* and *Joel*.

Comment: $data[1]->[0] can be written as $data[1][0], Perl understands what is going on there.

Comment: Bill Ruppert: Yes. However, I mostly use the former notation as it is a bit more explicit. :-)

Comment: may I also suggest perldoc perlreftut (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) which has great descriptions and only a few rules for creation and accessing data in references

Comment: Bill Ruppert and Joel: Edited answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Bill - it's a fairly widely held (though possibly a minority) view that omitting arrow separators decreases readability, especially in cases where subscripts to hashes/arrays are anything more complicated than string/integer literals. In other words, "can" doesn't necessarily mean "should" :)